# Как спозиционировать окно?

Tags: javascript, css

На [этой странице](http://lpsystem.ru/window.html) по ссылке, расположенной в середине страницы находится ссылка, которая открывает всплывающее окно. Окно при открытии находится в самом верху и не попадает в область видимости пользователя. Как спозиционировать окно, чтобы оно, например, всплывало в области видимости пользователя (например, отступом 100 пикселей от верхней границы браузера), в независимости от того, до какого момента пользователь прокрутил страницу.
Position:fixed не подходит, так как всплывающее окно может быть большой высоты, превышающей высоту монитора.

Comment: position: fixed;

Comment: так почему ? сделайте у #dim скролл и всё, position fixed у #dim, overflow: auto;

Comment: делайте jsfiddle/jsbin вместо вашей страницы.

Comment: а я в дебагере прописал у вас на странице и все работает. научитесь пожалуйста, всё там понятно.

Comment: @Виктор Павлов может немного не в тему, но вы вообще уверены, что всплывающее окно, размер которого может быть больще размера экрана - это хорошая идея?

Comment: Можно узнать значение текущей прокрутки и прибавить к нему ваши 100 пикселей. В результате получите значение "top" для абсолютно позиционированного элемента.
Значение текущей прокрутки: 
scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || document.documentElement.scrollTop;

Подробнее смотрите здесь: http://learn.javascript.ru/metrics-window

Comment: Почему 100 пикселей? Это к примеру. Вы увидели, в чём там проблема? Окно не поподает в область видимости.

Comment: eicto, оказывается оверфлоу не работает в хроме, яндекс.браузере, поэтому у меня ничего и не работало.